# PHP Regex Unknown Modifier

Tags: php, regex

Read a ton, didn't see an answer.  Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Running PHP 5.4.

I have a form that takes Contact Info (name, email, number, etc).

The regex I would like is:
only allow letters, numbers, a space, a dash, a backslash, a colon, an @ sign, and a forward slash.

This is what I'm using (for all input values, only showing one below):

```
if (!preg_match("/^[./\\@\w\sa-zA-Z0-9:-]+$/", $_POST["Name"])
```

I keep getting unknown modifier error.  I don't care if the above is fixed, or replaced with a different regex, i just need to allow only the things i mentioned earlier.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `/`

This should be

```
^[.\/\\@\w\sa-zA-Z0-9-]+$
```

Test your regex pattern at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/nZ6lT9/2)

---

- `\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]` If you are looking for space only the use
- `\w` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` that includes underscore as well. Just remove it from your regex pattern

---

only allow letters, numbers, a space, a dash, a backslash, a colon, an @ sign, and a forward slash.

It should be `^[0-9a-zA-Z \\:@\/-]+$`

**Note:** Make sure hyphen `-` must be in the beginning or ending of the Character class or should be escaped because hyphen has special meaning in Character class to define a range.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
if (!preg_match('~^[./\\\@\w\s:-]+$~', $_POST["Name"])
```

i.e. use an alternate delimiter like `~`, other than `/` since your regex is also using `/` in it.

I have also remove `[a-zA-Z0-9]` since you already have `\w` (word character) in your character class.

Comment: I marked the other guy as answer, since he replied first, but I really appreciate your additions.  Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, I needed to escape the backslash one more time.
So it's : '~^[./\\\@\w\s:-]+$~'

Comment: Yes just noticed and updated for anyone accessing this thread in future.